# What is the name for this definition of nabla using integral?

Tags: terminology, vector-analysis

I was taught that operator $\nabla$ can be defined as follows:

$$
\nabla = \lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \frac1{\mu V} \oint\limits_{\partial V} n \, \mathrm{d}S
$$

where $V$ is a region of space, $\partial V$ is it's boundary, $\mu V$ is the volume, $\delta$ is the diameter and $n$ is the normal vector on the boundary. And the operator works by taking whatever comes after it and inserting it after $n$.

Unfourtunately, I can find nothing on this formula (not even the formula itself) in English. We called this the invariant definition in Latvian. [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla#Definici%C3%B3n_intr%C3%ADnseca) and [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operatore_nabla#Definizione_intrinseca) wikipedia seem to call it the intrinsic definition. [Dutch](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla#Co%C3%B6rdinaatonafhankelijke_definitie) seem to call it coordinate agnostic definition. But googling these terms combined with "nabla" don't produce any relevant results in English.

Comment: The statement itself is a kind of Lebesgue differentiation theorem, looking that up might lead you somewhere. I'd also suggest using the word "gradient".

Comment: @Ian: I _think_ the point is that the surface integral formulation would work for gradients _and_ divergences _and_ curls.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Those terms are useful too. Just the actual word "nabla" isn't used in English text very much in my experience.

Comment: @Ian I think this is how a lot of physics textbooks define the divergence

Comment: @qbert From the point of view of physics, the divergence is an extreme limit of the flux through small spheres, which are the real physical quantity, so I wouldn't be surprised to hear that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perhaps more natural, due to divergence/Gauss theorem, to define divergence (and not del, at least at first) similar to what you present. If you go to [Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) wikipedia page, you'll find this definition (which is mentioned every once ina while, specially in physics books on electromagnetism). This may be referred to as the "coordinate-free" definition of divergence:

$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}:=\mathrm{div} (\mathbf{F}):=
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{1}{\mu V}\int_{\partial V} \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{F}dS
$$
Furthermore, one can define $\mathrm{grad}(f):=\nabla f$ and $\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf{F}):=\nabla\times \mathbf{F}$, as the unique vectors such that for all constant vectors $\mathbf{c}$, we have
$$
\mathrm{div}(f\mathbf{c})=\mathrm{grad}(f)\cdot \mathbf{c}, \qquad \mathrm{div}(\mathbf{F}\times \mathbf{c}):=\mathrm{curl}(\mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{c}
$$
One can then use the above coordinate-free definitions for divergence, gradient and curl, to give a corodinate-free definition for $\nabla$ which is exactly as you defined.